# Python - WebScraping using Request module-URL throws an error -403- forbidden

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the data from https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/ECFR?page=browse
using requests module in python

Somehow I'm getting HTTP 403-forbidden.

```
header = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0", 
"Host": "httpbin.org", 
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36", 
"X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ef3288f-10e678d0e55c0670c0807730"}
```

`r = requests.get(url , headers= header)`

I have also requested using user-agent and **all** the parameters in headers info(which I'm seeing in developer tools) .

I have tried using free proxies / rotating user header /cookies and everything i can get my hands on. But somehow website is able to know that I'm not using header.

In the html response - I'm seeing that website is asking to complete captcha.

Is there anyways I can skip that ?

Comment: That is the whole point of captchas. They are designed to be unskippable. Look for an API or something, there is no sure way other than that.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the http requests, I've found the cloudflare server response trace:

[image]

The **Cloudflare** or **ScrapeShield** is famous for its scrape protection, security levels. [Read more here](https://webscraping.pro/scrapeshield-limited-feature-anti-content-duplicate-tool/).

> Is there anyways I can skip that ?

There are 2 ways out:

1. Apply (plug-in) a captcha solving service. That is not that easy providing you use sole python coding.
2. Leverage the browser automation, making ScrapeShield to think that *a real user browses the website*. It does take **much more resources and time** (incl. development time). See [a scrape speed comparison table](https://webscraping.pro/scraping-a-javascript-dependent-website-with-puppeteer/#nr) of Chromium headless instance automation vs bare http requests.